# Can We make a SharePoint 2010 list to open in Datasheet View by default?

Tags: javascript, list-view, view

Is there any JavaScript which will force a SharePoint 2010 list to open in Datasheet view ?

Answer (score 3):

Create your desired view as a datasheet view with all the columns and filters you want, and in the view configuration, tell it to make it the default view. This will make it the default view for the users and will be in datasheet view, no customization necessary.

Comment: can we do it by using JavaScript only ?

Comment: There could be, but it is one of those things that doesn't make sense to do as they have built this in for you, just set a new view as the default view.

Comment: Users have IE08 as their default browser . There are a lot of users not added the site into campatability view  . Pushing all users for adding the site to compatabilty view or upgrade IE08 to IE11 will take a lot time .

Comment: Thats why we need a javascript.

Comment: That can be done via group policy pretty easily,http://windowsitpro.com/windows/jsi-tip-6644-how-can-i-use-group-policy-add-site-trusted-sites-zone

Comment: There are 20-30 zones of same client . Enforcing IT departments of those zones to do setting of comparability  will risk other applications . So we need a solution based on  JavaScript only .